# Collisions with Separate instances of the same class in Java

Tags: java

I have a JFrame that has two different JPanels in it one being a list of buttons, the other being the creation window. When you press one of the buttons on the JPanel it sets a toggle that allows you to click on the screen and place objects. All objects are 50x50 pixels and I am able to snap them into a grid based on where you click with the mouse. I need to know how to detect collisions when they are snapped in that grid like layout I created so I can adjust the image that was placed based on the location of other objects around it.

I am making a visual circuit board, I am able to drop switches onto the JPanel as a JLabel with a setIcon("picture") and want to be able to change that picture based on the location of the other instances of the same class. I want to set a connection line from the switches that would lead into gates and eventually to an Led. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am very new to Java and this is also my first post on the site, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

keep a boolean array b[m][n]. if something snaps to [i][j] then: if(b[i][j]) you have a collision, otherwise set b[i][j]=true;

Comment: Thank you I shall give that a try!